# Delete a record xamarin

Tags: c#, android, linq, xamarin

I am trying to let the user delete a record from the database but it wont let me do it. Can anyone suggest a way to do so?

```
List<Booking> item = new List<Booking>();
item = await BookingsTable
            .Where(todoItem => todoItem.Email == "email" && todoItem.Slot == 9)
            .ToListAsync();

if (item != null)
{
    //delete the record here
}
```

Comment: `it wont let me do it`? Assuming Sqlite? What DB framework are you using? What code are you using to use?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#querying

Comment: What you've written is capable of returning multiple items, and will never return null. If you know for sure there's only ever 1 or 0 items returned you can change item to be of type Booking (or Booking? in C# 8) and use .FirstOrDefaultAsync() instead of ToListAsync(). Then once you have the item and you know it's not null, I assume you can do BookingsTable.Remove(item) and SaveChanges() on the db context, though I'm not familiar with Azure Easy tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Booking> item = new List<Booking>();
item = await BookingsTable
            .Where(todoItem => todoItem.Email == "email" && todoItem.Slot == 9)
            .ToListAsync();

if (item != null)
{
    await BookingsTable.DeleteAsync(item);
}
```

does what you require - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#deleting